# Prolog challenge

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have the below implementation for the sublist algorithm. 
Problem: Given 2 lists, determine whether one is a sublist of the other.
I would really need another distinct solution in Prolog.

Solution one:

```
sublist([H1|T1], L, [H2|T2]):-
  H1 = H2,
  sublist(T1, L, T2).
sublist([], _, _)
sublist([H1|T1],L,[H2|T2]):-
  sublist(L,L,T2).
```

Solution two:

```
sublist([H|T], [H|L]):- check(T,L),
sublist(S, [H|T]):- sublist(S,T).
check([H|T], [H|R]):-
   check(T,R).
check([],_).
```

Solution three:

```
sublist(S,L):-
  append(_,R,L),
  append(S,_,R).
```

Solution three':

```
sublist(S,L):-
  append3(_,S,_,L).
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly by a list being a sublist of the other? because there are several interpretations. I.e. which ones of these queries should succeed `sublist([a,b,c], [a, c])`, `sublist([a, b, c], [c, a])`, `sublist([a, b, c], [a, b])`?

Comment: The right examples are: ?-sublist([a b c], [d e b a b c f])  True \n ?-sublist([a b c], [a e b f c]) Fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?- phrase((...,seq(Sublist),...),List).
```

with:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).
```

(Warning: In order to be able to explain this solution, you need to understand DCGs first!)

Comment: This is a good solution, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist([], _).
sublist([H|T], List) :-
    select(H, List, R),!,
    sublist(T, R).
```

You could make it more efficient if the lists were ordered to begin with.

Depending on your dialect of Prolog, `select/3` may have a different name.

Caveat: as per false's comment, this is rather "subset" than "sublist".

Comment: For `?- sublist([a,c],[a,b,c]).` your solution succeeds which is probably not intended.

Comment: Hm. Depends on whether the list is used to represent a set or a list proper. Since I normally use lists as sets, this may have biased my thinking. If the list represents a sequence, and the sublist is meant to be a partial sequence, then you're right.

Comment: There is this ambiguity about sequences and sets. Nevertheless: `sublist([a,c],[A,B,c]).` should then produce a fitting answer.

Comment: The sublist is a partial sequence of the initial list. EX: sublist ([a b], [x a b c]) retruns true, while sublist([a,c], [a b c]) fails